# Accessing static folder in flask

Tags: python, flask

We have written our custom rule in our function that handles URL mapping for our application. We wrote something like `app.add_url_rule('rule/for/custom/paths')`. Whenever we try to access the contents of static folder, it hits the custom rule that we wrote.

Apart from using Sub Domains for this purpose, do we have any other alternative to access the static files ?

Comment: You can always rename the static rule to use a different path; your custom rule and the static rule appear to overlap at the moment. Can you share us a little more detail?

Comment: I did try renaming it but it still maps to the custom rule

Comment: Then *show us your code*.

Comment: Does your custom route look something like this `add_url_rule("/<controller>/<action>/<argument>")`?

Comment: @SeanVieira: shouldn't that be sorted after the `/static/<path:filename>` route? A static first component is usually sorted earlier in the mapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom rule and the value of the [`static_url_path` parameter](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Flask) overlap. Rename one or the other.

You can easily use a different URL path for the static resources, for example:

```
 app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/assets')
```

would set the URL path for static resources to `/assets`; as long as you are using `url_for('static', filename='path/to/static/asset')` in your Flask code and templates, that's all you need to do to avoid clashing.